# obj export not showing in element 3d

Tags: export

I am trying to export an obj file from Blender and import it into After Effects via Element 3D. As far as I can tell, the export from Blender works fine, but when I try to import the file into Element 3D nothing is shown (even though when I select the file E3D does show it in the preview window). All I can see in the Element 3D window is an empty coordinate system.

I attached pictures with all the export and import options, did I forget something? I also checked normals (which are aligned correctly) and tested it with materials attached (which made no difference).

Many thanks in advance :)

[image: Blender Export]

[image: Element 3D]

Comment: Try oping the exported obj in a different program (even blender) if the export is ok, then this is a element 3d issue, and not on topic for this site. However if the obj is not exporting correctly, please edit your question and add more details on the export process.

Comment: Also check if the object geometry is not severely off-centered in relation to its local origin. Object may be successfully imported, just moved away from view.

Comment: I found the issue when I imported and it and seemed blank, was that it imported really small. Scale up first before you close it.